# SIGSEGV crash on main thread

Tags: ios

the Tencent bugly reports the following crash, However, i'm unable to detect why my app is crashing. Any ideas?

```
libobjc.A.dylib objc_object::release() + 16
1 libobjc.A.dylib   (anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) + 844
2 libobjc.A.dylib   (anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) + 844
3 UIKit ___handleEventQueueInternal + 4892
4 UIKit ___handleHIDEventFetcherDrain + 152
5 CoreFoundation    ___CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
6 CoreFoundation    ___CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 276
7 CoreFoundation    ___CFRunLoopRun + 1204
8 CoreFoundation    CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 552
9 GraphicsServices  GSEventRunModal + 100
10 UIKit    UIApplicationMain + 236
11 QYReaderApp  0x0000000100e84000 + 972980
12 libdyld.dylib    _start + 4
```

Comment: How often does the crash happen? and can you locate which file/page the crash happens in your app? the system version? devices? it can be for many reasons.

Comment: sorry, I can not get any useful information from your description. can you tell me more details about this crash?

Comment: year, I can't locate which page/file is crashing. but I think it relate with memory warning or Front and back ground switching. so I list device crash info:
![crashDevice](https://junhg521.github.io/JSSource/QRReader/1535420627242.jpg).

Comment: I think it is a frequently crashed bug, you just need to test it with your crash devices. you can find it out then.